# Array of user defined struct in Eigen

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, eigen

I wonder whether it is possible to adapt an array with more complex data to be used as an vector or matrix in Eigen.

example:

```
struct data
{
    /* some members...*/
    double numericValue;
    /* more members...*/
};
std::vector<data*> dataset;
```

is it possible to tell eigen how to access the *numericValue* member and use *dataset* for calculations?
I found the *map* class in the docs but not the required functionality.
Any ideas?

Comment: I hope you don't leak `data` instances in your code, a vector with pointer members often is a bad idea. Better use `valgrind --leak-check=full` on your executable for debugging purposes.

Comment: Pointer members are not really a problem, and in my case I thinks its the best way. What I am doing is build a quadtree, do some quadtree specific operations and vector algebra based operations on it.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand you question correctly, but that you have structured data, in which you have interleaved elements, that you would like to combine into a Vector or Matrix in order to perform Eigen Operations on it.

If this is what you are interested in, indeed the [Map type](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Map.html) is your friend. The following expression should give you what you want (untested):

```
typedef Map<VectorXd, 0, InnerStride<sizeof(data)/sizeof(double)> > MyMap;
MyMap map( &dataset[0].numericValue, dataset.size() );
```

now you can e.g. do something like

```
map *= 2.0;
```

in order multiply all your numericValue members by 2.0.

Comment: A good solution but does this also work with a array of pointers?

Comment: Ah... missed that one in the original question. In that case you can't really make any assumptions about the layout of your data in memory. The only thing I could think of there would be to use [customised types](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/TopicCustomizingEigen.html) to cover for the indirection with the pointer. You may however consider if this option is worth the effort.